# Passing props to a Function as a Child component

Tags: reactjs, react-virtualized

This works, but I need to separate out the `cellRenderer` component.

```
// Grid.js
import React, { Component } from "react";

class Grid extends Component {
  render() {
    const index = 3;
    return (
      <div style={{ height: "5em", width: "6em", border: "1px solid black" }}>
        {this.props.text}
        {this.props.children({ index, cellText: "no." })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Grid;
```

And `App.js`. If I click on "no.3", it correctly logs "x: 6"

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Grid from "./Grid";

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      x: 5
    };
  }

  handleIncrement = () => {
    this.setState(
      state => ({ x: state.x + 1 }),
      () => console.log(`x: ${this.state.x}`)
    );
  };

  cellRenderer = ({ index, cellText }) => {
    return <div onClick={() => this.handleIncrement()}>{cellText + index}</div>;
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Grid text={"Hello "}>{this.cellRenderer}</Grid>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Now, if I have to separate out `cellRenderer` component as below, how can I pass the `handleIncrement` function to it ?

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Grid from "./Grid";

const cellRenderer = ({ index, cellText }) => {
  return <div>{cellText + index}</div>;
};

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      x: 5
    };
  }

  handleIncrement = () => {
    this.setState(
      state => ({ x: state.x + 1 }),
      () => console.log(`x: ${this.state.x}`)
    );
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Grid text={"Hello "}>{cellRenderer}</Grid>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**Edit:**

This works:

```
// pass handleIncrement to Grid
<Grid text={"Hello "} handleIncrement={this.handleIncrement} >{cellRenderer}</Grid>

// And within Grid, pass it to cellRenderer
{this.props.children({ index, cellText: "no.", handleIncrement: this.props.handleIncrement })}

// Update cellRenderer to this
const cellRenderer = ({ index, cellText, handleIncrement }) => {
    return <div onClick={handleIncrement}>{cellText + index}</div>;
};
```

But the problem is that `Grid` is a component from the library `react-window`, and I cannot override the library code. Any other way possible ?

Comment: You can just use the component syntax for stateless, functional components: `<CellRenderer />` then pass in the props the traditional way. Also if there's no arguments then just pass the function itself as the prop, not an anonymous function which calls it, e.g. change `onClick={() => this.handleIncrement()}` to simply `onClick={this.handleIncrement}`

Comment: If you're using `react-window` and need to pass down props to the renderer, take a look at the `itemData` prop as this will likely get you what you need (https://react-window.now.sh/#/api/FixedSizeList). If this doesn't suit your needs, the [React context API](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) might come in handy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that you have separated our `cellRenderer` as a functional component, you could render it as a component and pass on the props

```
const CellRenderer = ({ index, cellText, handleIncrement }) => {
  return <div onClick={handleIncrement}>{cellText + index}</div>;
};
...

return (
      <div className="App">
        <Grid text={"Hello "}>{({index, cellText}) => <CellRenderer handleIncrement={this.handleIncrement} index={index} cellText={cellText}/>}</Grid>
      </div>
    );
```

Comment: This doesn't work ... <Grid> expects function as a child and CellRenderer gets its cellText from <Grid>. Pls. see my edit to the question

Answer (score 1):

This will work:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import Grid from './components/Grid'

const CellRenderer = ({ index, cellText, handleIncrement }) => {
  return <div onClick={handleIncrement}>{cellText + index}</div>
}

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      x: 5
    }
  }

  handleIncrement = () => {
    this.setState(
      state => ({ x: state.x + 1 }),
      () => console.log(`x: ${this.state.x}`)
    )
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Grid text={'Hello '}>
          {props => (
            <CellRenderer {...props} handleIncrement={this.handleIncrement} />
          )}
        </Grid>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default App
```